# Arduino led matrix max7219 MCU Board Dot Matrix

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am a 14 years student and I have not a good knowledge about arduino . I bought a max7219 MCU Board Dot Matrix for my uno.
Can I display some letters in matrix by adding `digital.write` or `matrix.write`.

Comment: Install library for MAX7219 and try examples

Comment: And next steps are: try to understand what is happening in the example and try to add/change something related to the matrix